# Determine how regular a set of points is?

Tags: algorithm, movement-data

I'm trying to cluster some gps data to accurately determine stop points for vehicle movements on a testing grid. I know the points they stop at are regular/closely match points on some defined grid of arbitrary regular polygons, and am able to generate good clusterings with manual supervision. I'm trying to write an extensible version of this process with automatic hyperparameter tuning and need some function to determine how regular the detected points are.

For example, f(lattice pts(25,25,5)) = 0, f(random points) = very high.

The closest idea I can come up with is fitting a lattice to the points with some uncertainty and measuring both the size of the lattice needed and the uncertainty, but it doesn't feel like a particularly elegant solution.